# Substitute Concrete Value in Conditional Expectation

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, random-functions, expectation

- Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.
- Let  $$ X, Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ be random variables.
- Furthermore, let
  $$ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
  be a $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function 
  such that, for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, the random variables $f(X,y)$ and 
  $f(X,Y)$ have finite expectation.

Now let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Under the above assumptions, the expected value $\mathbb{E}[f(X,y)]$  and a $\mathbb{P}$-unique conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid Y]$ do exist.

Furthermore, since $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable, there exists a $\mathbb{P}_Y$-unique $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function
$$ \varphi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
such that $\varphi(Y) = \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid Y]$.

Under which circumstances does it hold, that $\varphi$ can be chosen such that
$$ \varphi (y) = \mathbb{E}[f(X,y)]  $$
and why?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: The notion of a *regular conditional probabilit* (sometimes called a *transition kernel*) is usually helpful with this sort of thing. Do you have a particular set of circumstances where you'd like your $\varphi$ to exist?

Comment: *probability, not 'probabilit'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\vpi}{\varphi}$
The answer is: the condition

> $E(f(X,Y)|Y)=\vpi(Y)$ for all $f$ such that $f(X,Y)$ has a finite expectation

holds iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Indeed, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then for each Borel subset $B$ of $\R$
\begin{align*}
 EI\{Y\in B\}\vpi(Y)&=\int P(Y\in dy)I\{y\in B\}\vpi(y) \\ 
 &=\int P(Y\in dy)I\{y\in B\}Ef(X,y) \\ 
  &=\int P(Y\in dy)I\{y\in B\}\int P(X\in dx)f(x,y) \\ 
  &=\int P(X\in dx,Y\in dy)I\{y\in B\}f(x,y) \\ 
  &=EI\{Y\in B\}f(X,Y),
\end{align*}
where $I$ is the indicator. So, $E(f(X,Y)|Y)=\vpi(Y)$.

Vice versa, suppose that $E(f(X,Y)|Y)=\vpi(Y)$ for all $f$ such that $f(X,Y)$ has a finite expectation, where $\vpi(Y)=Ef(X,y)$ for all real $y$. Take any Borel subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\R$, and let $f(x,y):=I\{x\in A\}I\{y\in B\}$ for all real $x,y$. Then for each $y\in\R$
\begin{equation}
\vpi(y)=Ef(X,y)=EI\{X\in A\}I\{y\in B\}=P(X\in A)I\{y\in B\} 
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{align*}
P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)&=EP(X\in A)I\{Y\in B\} \\ 
&=EI\{Y\in B\}\vpi(Y) \\ 
 &=EI\{Y\in B\}f(X,Y) \\
 &=EI\{X\in A\}I\{Y\in B\}=P(X\in A,Y\in B),
\end{align*}
so that $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$.

Comment: Iosif, if $f(x,y) = I\{x \in A\} I\{y \in B\}$, then $\varphi(y)$ need not be equal $P(X \in A) I\{y \in B\}$! You are assuming independence here...

Comment: What happens $P_X$ and $P_Y$ supported on finite (or compact) sets and let $f(x,y)=1$?

Comment: I read this question as being about the functional $\mu_{X,Y,f}:\psi\longmapsto \int\int\psi(y)f(x,y)(dP^{X,Y}(x,y) - dP^X(x)dP^Y(y))$ for a fixed choice of $f$.

Comment: I was going to use the word *distribution* instead of `functional' there for a second...

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki : Mateusz, I don't know why you said "need not". I was certainly not assuming any independence at that point. If $f(x,y)=I\{x\in A\}I\{y\in B\}$ for all real $x,y$, then for each $y\in\mathbb R$ we have $\varphi(y)=Ef(X,y)=EI\{X\in A\}I\{y\in B\}=P(X\in A)I\{y\in B\}$. Here, $y$ is just a real number (not a random variable), and hence $I\{y\in B\}$ is also just a real number. I have added this little detail to the answer. Please let me know whether this convinces you.

Comment: @DCM : This answer provides a proof of just what is stated there, concerning all functions $f$ such that $f(X,Y)$ has a finite expectation. I would be much surprised if one could prove anything of interest for a fixed $f$. Can you do that?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Ah, OK, now I see: you take $\varphi(y) = \mathbb{E} f(X,y)$ as a definition of $\varphi$. In the question, $\varphi$ was chosen so that $\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y)|Y) = \varphi(Y)$, and OP asks whether $\varphi(y) = \mathbb{E} f(X,y)$. Sorry for misunderstanding!

Comment: @IosifPinelis: I don't disagree with anything you've written, it just seemed to me that the OP was asking a slightly different question. It seems not given that the OP has accepted your answer :)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki : I am glad the matter is cleared now. In the "vice versa" part of the proof, I should have repeated the assumption in the OP that $\varphi(y)=Ef(X,y)$, which is done now. Sorry for that omission, which resulted in the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't an answer, just a (hopefully correct and useful) reformulation of the question**

Let $f$ be as stipulated (*and assumed fixed throughout*). The equation $E(f(X,Y)|Y) = u(Y)$ is just a way of saying that $u$ satisfies

$$
\int f(x,y)\psi(y)dP^{X,Y}(x,y) = \int u(y)\psi(y)dP^Y(y)
$$

for all $\psi$ in a suitably large class of test functions. The question here is under what circumstances is the function $u$ defined by

$$
u(y) =\int f(x,y)dP^X(x)
$$

a solution to all these equations. That is, when is it true that

$$
\int\int f(x,y)\psi(y)dP^{X,Y}(x,y)  = \int \left(\int f(x,y)dP^X(x)\right)\psi(y)dP^Y(y)
$$

for all test functions $\psi$? Re-arranging this equation slightly, our question becomes: when is it true that

$$
\int \int \psi(y)f(x,y)\left( dP^{X,Y}(x,y) - dP^X(x)dP^Y(y)\right) = 0
$$

for all test functions $\psi$?.

**Edit:** I don't disagree with anything in Iosif's answer, but my initial feeling (before you accepted his answer) was that you were asking a slightly different question. Whether anything interesting can be said for my question is perhaps a matter for another occasion.